# VLookup function range in Excel using macro

Tags: excel, range, vlookup, vba

I am trying to make a macro to do the vlookup in excel. I have succeed to create and the code is working fine!
The code as below:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],LW0640!R2C8:R12163C9,2,TRUE)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D6:D6098")`

However, I found that the range is fix range. which is from D6:D6098 on the result and R2C8:R12163C9 from the source.

And it will not work if the data range changes.
I want to know how to make the range for the vlookup function from the beginning until the last row in the range.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "A1" type of notation. In your case, you want column 8 and 9, which are respectively H and I, so you can write the following:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],LW0640!H:I" & MyCols & ",2,TRUE)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D6:D6098")
```

Comment: do you mean it will select all the row in column H and I?

Comment: yes, but I am not sure whether it works with the older versions of Excel...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
Sheets("LW0640").Select
Range("D6:D6098").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="tablex", RefersToR1C1:= _
        "=LW0640!R6C4:R6098C4"


'Range("F28").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],tablex,2,TRUE)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")  'change Sheet1 to your data sheet
    With ws
        LastRow = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("D6:D" & LastRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(C6,LW0640!$H$2:$I$" & LastRow & ",2,TRUE)"
    End With
End Sub
```

You should avoid using `SELECT` and `ACTIVE`. See [this](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/04/27/beginning-vba-select-and-activate/) for details.